# Oculus Rift with Unity crashing on play

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus

I have installed the `Oculus SDK` for Windows and the Oculus Run-time for Windows. I set stereoscopic and VR enabled to true in the player settings in Unity. I am running Windows 8 with:

> Unity 5.1.2f1
>
> Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000
>
> NVIDIA GeForce GTX 660 M

When I hit play, the screen goes black, the laptop makes a screeching sound, and then I get a notification in the bottom right hand of my screen that says my Intel(R) HD card stopped working but has recovered.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please read the tag descriptions, [tag:Unity] explicitly states it is not for the Unity game engine and that you need to use [tag:unity3d] instead

Answer (score 0):

Does the Oculus demo scene work? What version of the runtime do you have? If the demo scene doesn't work, it's probably the 2 graphics cards you have running. You're on a laptop right? Try turning the intel one off in the BIOS.

Comment: I turned the intel graphics card off and now stopped getting the error, however, when I run the Oculus Config util I get the following error: HMD powered off, check HDMI connection.

Comment: Do you have the correct [nvidia driver](https://developer.nvidia.com/gameworks-vr-driver-support)? and the 0.8 oculus runtime?

Answer (score 0):

try Upgrading your Intel HD driver you can download it from [here](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/81499/Intel-HD-Graphics-4000-for-3rd-Generation-Intel-Core-Processors)